# Subset data.table by one variable based on conditional values in other variables

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a data.table in R that I need to subset based on certain conditions

```
dt <- data.table(X_ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4), Y_ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6, 1,2,3,4,5,6), Value1=c(6,4,8,9,10,12,5,7,8,3,4,8,7,3,9,7,4,12,45,3,2,1,2,5),Value2=c(6,6,8,9,10,12,5,4,8,3,4,8,7,5,9,7,4,12,45,1,2,1,2,5))
```

I want to retain all X_ID's in which value 1 is greater than value 2 when Y_ID is equal to 2. E.g., for X_ID=1, value 1 is greater than value 2 when Y_ID=2. In this case, I want to retain all rows that have X_ID=1.

I am currently using the filter function (shown below) to get at the solution.

```
dt2 <- filter(dt,is.na(match(dt$X_ID,filter(dt, Y_ID==2&Value1<Value2)$X_ID)))
```

But is there a way to make this code more readable? Or use something native to data.table to subset the rows I require?

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
    dt<-dt[X_ID %in% dt[(Y_ID == 2 & (Value1 > Value2))]$X_ID]

#    X_ID Y_ID Value1 Value2
#1:    2    1      5      5
#2:    2    2      7      4
#3:    2    3      8      8
#4:    2    4      3      3
#5:    2    5      4      4
#6:    2    6      8      8
#7:    4    1     45     45
#8:    4    2      3      1
#9:    4    3      2      2
#10:    4    4      1      1
#11:    4    5      2      2
#12:    4    6      5      5
```

Comment: Just noticed that the subsetting code mentioned above doesn't change the original data.table which still contains 24 rows (unlike other data.table operations like adding new calculated columns where the original data.table would also get updated inline with new columns being added). I need to assign this output to a new data.table to store the rows that got selected. Out of curiosity, any idea why this difference between different types of operations in data.table?

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` we can `group_by` `X_ID` and `filter` for groups where there is at least one value for `Y_ID == 2` and `Value1 > Value2`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(X_ID) %>%
  filter(any(Y_ID == 2 & Value1 > Value2))

#    X_ID  Y_ID Value1 Value2
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     2     1      5      5
# 2     2     2      7      4
# 3     2     3      8      8
# 4     2     4      3      3
# 5     2     5      4      4
# 6     2     6      8      8
# 7     4     1     45     45
# 8     4     2      3      1
# 9     4     3      2      2
#10     4     4      1      1
#11     4     5      2      2
#12     4     6      5      5
```